# spring jpa update one record in different transaction. deadlock

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, deadlock

**The mysql log(show engine innodb status) is**

```
(1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 255071, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 3625, OS thread handle 0x7f2eecd5eb00, query id 323014 localhost 127.0.0.1 root updating
update t_challenge_records set CREATED=1514179337707, STATUS='PROCESSING', UPDATED=1514275693337, CID=7, ENDDATE=20180101, ENDTIMED=180000, ENDTIMEU=0, ISSUE=null, LATESTDATE=20171226, LATESTTIME=160813, MONEY=5500, ORDERNO='201712222324423707842', PROFIT=0, REASON=null, ROOM='34', STARTDATE=20171226, STARTTIMED=70000, STARTTIMEU=0, SUBTYPE='D', TYPE='CUSTOM', USER='59f15fd966ec7707bc7a708e' where ID=33

 (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 264 page no 3 n bits 80 index `PRIMARY` of table `seblong`.`t_challenge_records` trx table locks 3 total table locks 4  trx id 255071 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting lock hold time 0 wait time before grant 0 

 (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 255072, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 3626, OS thread handle 0x7f2eef9b4b00, query id 323015 localhost 127.0.0.1 root updating
update t_challenge_records set CREATED=1514179337707, STATUS='PROCESSING', UPDATED=1514275693337, CID=7, ENDDATE=20180101, ENDTIMED=180000, ENDTIMEU=0, ISSUE=null, LATESTDATE=20171226, LATESTTIME=160813, MONEY=5500, ORDERNO='201712222324423707842', PROFIT=0, REASON=null, ROOM='34', STARTDATE=20171226, STARTTIMED=70000, STARTTIMEU=0, SUBTYPE='D', TYPE='CUSTOM', USER='59f15fd966ec7707bc7a708e' where ID=33

(2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 264 page no 3 n bits 80 index `PRIMARY` of table `seblong`.`t_challenge_records` trx table locks 3 total table locks 4  trx id 255072 lock mode S locks rec but not gap lock hold time 0 wait time before grant 0 

(2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 264 page no 3 n bits 80 index `PRIMARY` of table `seblong`.`t_challenge_records` trx table locks 3 total table locks 4  trx id 255072 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting lock hold time 0 wait time before grant 0

 WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

who can explain the log? Thanks.! And the main entity code is below

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "t_challenge_records", indexes = { @Index(columnList = 
  "USER"), @Index(columnList = "TYPE"),
    @Index(columnList = "STATUS"), @Index(columnList = "CREATED"), 
    @Index(columnList = "ORDERNO"),
    @Index(columnList = "CID"), @Index(columnList = "ISSUE"), 
    @Index(columnList = "MONEY"),
    @Index(columnList = "PROFIT"), @Index(columnList = "LATESTDATE") 
 })
 public class ChallengeRecord extends AbstractBaseEntity {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "ID")
 private Long id;
 private long cId;
 private String user;
 private String type;
 private String subType;;
 private int startDate;
 private int endDate;
 private int latestDate;
 private int latestTime;
 private int startTimeU;
 private int endTimeU;
 private int startTimeD;
 private int endTimeD;
 private String room; 
 private String issue; 
 private long money;
 private long profit;
 private String orderNO;
 private String reason;
```

Above is the Entity of jpa, And the update method is just find the record,and alter the param of date and time. Then it generate the deadlock.  Who could help me ?

Comment: First of all the log shows that there are two exactly the same `UPDATE` commands that trying to update the same record `ID=33` with exactly the same values. The main reason is that your code performs **the same** UPDATE command **twice in two different sessions**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but, I don't know why the mysql generate the deadlock. In my opinion, the first Transaction will lock the row, and the second transaction will wait the lock until the first release, but from the result, it is not right.

Comment: I know this is a bug of my code, but I think this could't generate the deadlock, so I want to know why.

Comment: Then please share your code so we could know whether your code already handle deadlock situation or not.

Comment: The code don't handle this exception .The main reason is the concurrent, it generate this deadlock when we carry out the concurrent test.